# Windows 10: No Sound coming out of earphones (only speakers work)

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10

#### It's a laptop (dual booting Win10[recently upgraded from win7 64bit] and Elementary OS Freya)

#### It's nothing to do with hardware issues

Earphones worked fine on my Elementary OS so my audio jack is definitely not broken or anything like that. Earphones work on my phone as well so i'm quite positive it's to do with windows 10 only.

#### No sound coming out of earphones

There's no sound coming out of the earphones, and I'm sure it's nothing to do with them because they work fine when I plug them into my phone. Also, I've tried another pair of earphones which resulted the same. However, the sound works perfectly without the earphones plugged into my laptop, the speakers are fine.

#### unsure if it's to do with drivers

I've tried uninstalling the Realtek HD audio drivers, reinstalling and nothing works.

However, I have Windows 10 but could only find drivers for Windows 7/8

#### settings

I've googled a bit and most would suggest something like checking the playback devices but the only one on my list is 'Speakers'.

#### Realtek detected my earphones

When I plug in my earphones, Realtek detected them and even popped up the notification saying *'you just plugged a device into the audio jack'*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzQpQ.jpg
as shown in the picture, when i toggle my mouse onto the black circle, it clearly detected something was plugged in, but somehow audio just won't play through my earphones.

Comment: I'm on a laptop, the laptop speakers work fine. Also, since i'm dual booting and earphones work fine on my linux, it's nothing to do with the jacks

Comment: where can i find the connector settings?

Comment: as you can see from my screenshot, there's only 'analog' on the right hand side. I tried to right click the black button but nothing happened

Comment: @Dave how can i check it?

Comment: no, 'headphone' is not shown as an option when i go to 'sounds' No matter what kind of earphone i plug in, 'speaker' is the only playback device

Comment: the thing is im on a windows 10, the manufacturers only has windows7/8 drivers available

Comment: You can get drivers directly from realtek website. And install it via device manager. Microsoft itself provide you suitable driver by Windows update. I'm not sure, you checked this or not, when you plug device, it selected automatically by Windows as speaker or ear phone etc, so check specific device volume after plug.

Comment: the only playback device on my laptop is the 'speaker' even though i plugged in my earphones. And yes, I downloaded the latest realtek drivers from their official website (ok i'll try reinstalling that from DEVICE MANAGER)

Comment: @Dave  dude, is it really necessary to downvote this.. I mean I didn't know you needed those details...jeeez

Answer (score 2):

## Uninstall Realtek and let Windows Update do the work

Turned out all I had to do was to uninstall the realtek and reboot. While the laptop was rebooting, windows update just fixed everything for me.

## Maybe my laptop doesn't need Realtek

After unistalling Realket and restarted my computer WITHOUT reinstalling any realtek drivers, the sound worked fine. I checked my device manager and instead of 'Realtek HD audio', i have 'HD audio device' which leads me to the conclusion that I don't actually need Realtek at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps that might help you:

https://fossbytes.com/windows-10-guide-how-to-fix-audio-issues-in-windows-10-pcs/

In my case after updating the sound drivers the problem continued, but what it worked was updating the BIOS and updating the Chipset drivers for your computer available from the manufacturer support page.